# C: What is a readable way to frequency count (as close to possible) the entire ascii table while reading strings

Tags: c, string, count

From this Web site 
http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-find-characters-frequency
They have an example that will count a - z but not A-Z or spaces or standard punctuations.

```
  while ( string[c] != '\0' )
  {
     /* Considering characters from 'a' to 'z' only */

     if ( string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z' ) 
        count[string[c]-'a']++;

     c++;
  }

  for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
  {
     if( count[c] != 0 )
```

Comment: What isn't readable about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count all characters in the string use an `int a[256]` and use the characters of the string as indexes into the array and increment:

```
int counts[256] = { 0 }; /* Initialize all elements to zero. */

while (string[c]) counts[(unsigned char)string[c++]]++;
```

Comment: Your intention is to allow and count all 8-bit chars. OK, but then you need to remember that `char` can be signed.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood your question, but I am concerned that I see no attempt to solve it before asking.

```
int count[ 256 ] ; // - make sure you change your declaration from [ 26 ]!

while ( string[c] != '\0' )
{
   count[( unsigned char )string[c]]++;
   c++;
}

for ( c = 1 ; c < 256 ; c++ ) // no point to check c == 0
{
   if( count[c] != 0 )
```

Comment: @Grzegorz, note this is C so no `static_cast`. ;)

Comment: @hmjd: Grrr. I am blind. I haven't paid attention to "C:"... thingi. Thank you both!