# Program that detects which letter is the most common

Tags: c, variables, loops, optimization

I am a beginner in C, I am trying to make a program which detects which letter is the most common of max 10 letters.
Here is what I've got so far:

```
char one = 'a'; //0110 0001
char check[10];

scanf("%s", &check);
char *ptr;
int a = 0;int b = 0;int c = 0;int d = 0;int e = 0;int f = 0;int g = 0;int h = 0;int i = 0;int j = 0;int k = 0;int l = 0;int m = 0;int n = 0;int o = 0;int p = 0;int q = 0;int r = 0;int s = 0;int t = 0;int u = 0;int v = 0;int w = 0;int x = 0;int y = 0;int z = 0;


if (check[0]=='a'){
    a += 1;
    if (a> b && a> c && a> d && a> e && a> f && a> g && a> h && a> i && a> j && a> k && a> l && a> m && a> n && a> o && a> p && a> q && a> r && a> s && a> t && a> u && a> v && a> x && a> y ){
        printf("A is the most common letter);
    }
}
```

The 'if' statement is only for the first letter that is entered and it is only checking the letter a.
Here is where I need help, how do I optimize that? How can I make a loop instead of having all that a>b && a>c ... etc. Also if it is possible to declare a lot of similar variables in a shorter way? Just generally how do I keep short and am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Fun fact: `e` is actually the most common letter in the english language.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904674/c-what-is-a-readable-way-to-frequency-count-as-close-to-possible-the-entire-a/14904723#14904723

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use loops and arrays. Just store the amount of letters you've got in an array and then compare current the letter amount to best amount:

```
char check[10];
scanf("%s", &check);
const int checkSize = strlen(check);

int numberOfLetters[26]; 
for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) 
    numberOfLetters[i] = 0;

int bestLetterIndex = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < checkSize; ++i) {
    int letterIndex = check[i] - 'a'; // getting index from ASCII code
    numberOfLetters[letterIndex]++;

    if(i == 0 || // first letter, index not found yet 
       numberOfLetters[letterIndex] > numberOfLetters[bestLetterIndex]) {
        bestLetterIndex = letterIndex;
    }
}

printf("Most common letter is %c", (char)(bestLetterIndex + 'a'));
```

Comment: This is honestly the closest answer to what the OP is actually looking for, and even it falls on an [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) platform (which has at-most *nine* consecutive characters before a break in the sequence. I.e. 'j' - 'a' is *not* 9; it is 16).

Comment: @WhozCraig haha, good one :) For reasons, i think OP doesn't care about such thing. Otherwise, he might be like 60 years old =D

Comment: He *should* care. its the difference between correct, and JGE (just-good-enough). "Correct" lasts, JGE is the source of plethoras of headaches in the future.

Comment: If you don't want to care about this sort of thing, don't write C code.

Comment: Explain the downvotes, please. OP didn't say anything about his system. I can bet a hundred that it's not that type of system where this code wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are doing a lot of things wrong.

**this part of code**

`int a = 0;int b = 0;int c = 0;int d = 0;int e = 0;int f = 0;int g = 0;int h = 0;int i = 0;int j = 0;int k = 0;int l = 0;int m = 0;int n = 0;int o = 0;int p = 0;int q = 0;int r = 0;int s = 0;int t = 0;int u = 0;int v = 0;int w = 0;int x = 0;int y = 0;int z = 0;`

is something horrific.

*Use an array, like that:*
`int letter[25];`

`letter[0]` will be your `a`, `letter[1]` will be your `b` ... `letter[49]` will be your `z`.

**this part of code**

```
if (check[0]=='a'){
    a += 1;
```

is a bad way to do what you want.

*you should do it like this:*

```
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if(check[i] >= 'A' && check[i] <= 'Z') // Check if letter is uppercase.
        ++letter[check[i] - 'A']; // 'A' == 65, But our array is from 0 to 49.

    if(check[i] >= 'a' && check[i] <= 'z') // Check if letter is lowercase.
        ++letter[check[i] - 'a']; // 'a' == 97. Note that 'A' is not 'a'.
}
```

This will check which character is most common, and stores it in the `letter` array.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do it your way and compare every letter with every other. But usually you do this in two phases

- count how often the letters occur

  ```
  int letters[26];
  int i, n = strlen(check), max;
  memset(letters, 0, sizeof(letters));
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      char c = tolower(check[i]);
      letters[c - 'a']++;
  }
  ```
- pick the highest one

  ```
  max = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < 26; ++i)
      if (letters[i] > letters[max])
          max = i;

  printf("%c is the most common letter\n", max + 'a');
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Impressive work :)

```
int counts[26]; // We are expecting 26 letters
char check[10];
char *ptr;
scanf("%s", check);

memset(counts, 0, sizeof(counts)); // zero all array values
for (ptr = check; *ptr; ptr++)
{
   char ch = *ptr;
   if (isalpha(ch)) // ignore non-alphas
   {
      ch = tolower(ch);
      counts[ch - 'a']++;
   }
}
```

You can add best index lookup code from `dreamzor` answer